# how to convert regex match to integer? (returns "Input string was not in a correct format")

Tags: c#, regex, string, integer

i have a problem in converting a regex match (that is basically a string) to an integer.

```
Match results = Regex.Match(websr.ReadToEnd(),
                            "\\d+\\S+\\d+ results", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var count = Regex.Match(results.ToString(), "\\d+\\S+\\d+");
```

these two lines are regex . i want to extract the number of results. "count" shows the correct number of results. in next step i want to convert it to integer type

i tried `{int countN = int.parse(count.ToString())}` or `{Int32.TryParse(count,out countN)}` and many other cases but returns `"Input string was not in a correct format"` or shows 0 in listbox.

i'm really confused by this.i tried many tricks but no success.
thanks for help :)

edit :
here is the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace bing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.bing.com/");
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader response1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            cookies = response.Cookies;

            try
            {
                string web = "http://www.bing.com";
                //post
                string getUrl = (web + "/search?q=" + textBox1.Text);


                HttpWebRequest webreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
                HttpWebResponse webrep = (HttpWebResponse)webreq.GetResponse();
                StreamReader websr = new StreamReader(webrep.GetResponseStream());
                Match results = Regex.Match(websr.ReadToEnd(), "\\d+\\S+\\d+ results", RegexOptions.Singleline);
                var count = Regex.Match(results.ToString(), "\\d+\\S+\\d+");
                int countN = int.Parse(count.Value);



                listBox1.Items.Add(countN.ToString());
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Put whichever one you want in a group and get the group instead.

Comment: It seems like there are non-digit characters in your matches. What do they look like?

Comment: it's a bing search result and i want to extract the number of search results (its like this "12345 Results")

Comment: Debug your code and see what `Regex.Match` returns before you invoke `int.parse`

Comment: it returns the correct number(number of search query results).but the issue is convert to integer.

Comment: @Sniper_ir if it would be a number you wouldn't get that execption. Debug again, or post a *self-containd, compilable* code that shows your problem.

Comment: @i4v edited and code added

Comment: @Sniper_ir your first Regex doesn't match anything. (See *Success* property)

Comment: @Sniper_ir I would also strongly recommend to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @i4v i tested code for the word "add" and listbox shows "32,700,000 results" !

Comment: @i4v the issue is not findin' the number of results.its about converting it to integer ( i think regex represents a string in it's match) :)

Comment: @Sniper_ir The issue is of course *finding the number*, if you could have found it(correctly), `int.parse` wouldn't throw exception, BTW: I don't know how you get this 32700000 results. Your code throws exception as expected.

Comment: @Sniper_ir Put MessageBox's for `results.ToString()` and `count.Value` (if you don't know how yo use VS's debugger)

Comment: @i4v i took a snapshot [link](http://postimg.org/image/p4pd0imc7/)

Comment: @i4v and this is for count [link](http://postimg.org/image/np41cire7/)

Comment: @Sniper_ir I get exceptions. Bing may produce different html's for different locales. This is also another reason why you should avoid to parse html with regex.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
var count = int.Parse(Regex.Match(results.ToString(), "\\d+\\S+\\d+").Value);
```

Verify there is only numbers in the input string.

Comment: has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

solved
when i extracted the result number, it was something like 123,456,789 and the problem was "," between digits.

```
Match results = Regex.Match(websr.ReadToEnd(), "\\d+\\S+\\d+ results", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match count = Regex.Match(results.ToString(), "\\d+\\S+\\d+");

string countN = count.Value.Replace(",", "");
int countM = int.Parse(countN);
```

and countM shows 123456789 
thanks to all friends whom answered :)